# How Can I Test My Project on Specific Version of Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am developing a web application using Angular 7. We regularly publish interim versions for our client to use. Recently, an innocuous `mouseover` based feature stopped working on my client's computers but it works fine on all of our development computers. Our client has a very 'managed' enterprise intranet and they use an earlier version of Chrome, we suspect that their installed version changed and that is when the problem started.

Is there any way I can install and run a previous version of Chrome to try and replicate their environment to help track down the bug please?

Comment: You can download older versions only from a third party. Google does not host older versions due to possible security issues.

Comment: You can use something like browserstack to simulate any version of most of the browsers out there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I didn't know about BrowserStack, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install previous versions of Chrome by downloading the older installers (Windows only) via a file sharing service. There are several online websites that provide archives of the older installers.

Once you've downloaded the `xxxxx.msi` file. You have to right-click and select "confirm digital signature" to ensure that the file came from Google. This verification happens from Windows and doesn't require that you download the installer from a trusted third party, because it performs a certificate check. If a single byte has been changed it will not verify and you know not to trust the installer. I was able to find several sources for installers just by searching for it.

View the digital signature and make sure it's from Google.

Before you run the installer. You have to make sure auto updates are disabled. There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest is to just rename the `\Program Files\Chrome\Update` folder.

https://www.webnots.com/7-ways-to-disable-automatic-chrome-update-in-windows-and-mac/

I do not know how to downgrade on Mac, but Chrome is not available on Linux. Most people run Chromium which is easily downgraded. So I just assumed you're on Windows.

Comment: That's very interesting to know thanks. I assumed an older version would simply update itself immediately upon installation.